# Translate string with wrong encoding

Tags: delphi, encoding

I have a dll function that returns a simple string.

I never had to use a string with accentuation (`à é í ô ü`, etc..) until now.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the DLL's code, and I cannot use another to fix the encoding.

Can I translate the string properly somehow?

Example: the string `Última posição` comes as `Ãšltima posiÃ§Ã£o`.

Comment: already tried `UTF8Decode()` function?

Comment: `UTF8Decode()` is the solution to your trouble.

Comment: It works! I used this in another situation and it didn't work, so I just assumed the function was the problem since it's deprecated.

Comment: well, based in your example(`Ãšltima posiÃ§Ã£o`), this is definitive solution. I think that not exists a generic function in Delphi able to translate any type of encoding.

Comment: `so I just assumed the function was the problem since it's deprecated`. Then try using [**`UTF8ToString()`**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UTF8ToString)

Comment: Or, you can copy/assign the raw data to a `UTF8String` and then assign that to a `UnicodeString`. The RTL will decode it automatically.

Comment: The [documentation for UTF8Decode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UTF8Decode) says *UTF8Decode is deprecated. Use UTF8ToString instead* in the middle of the page.